# Parsing simple XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<links>

  <item>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <url>http://www.example.com/url-1</url>
  </item>

  <item>
   <title>Title 2</title>
   <url>http://www.example.com/url-2</url>
  </item>

  <item>
    <title>Title 3</title>
    <url>http://www.example.com/url-3</url>
  </item>

</links>
```

And, I would like to convert it to a HTML list:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/url-1">Title 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/url-2">Title 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/url-3">Title 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Currently I have this:

Controller:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(...)

@links = doc.xpath('//links/item').map do |i|
  {'title' => i.xpath('//title'), 'url' => i.xpath('//url')}
end
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  <% @links.each do |l| %>
    <li><a href="<%= l['url'] %>"><%= l['title'] %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/url-1http://www.example.com/url-2http://www.example.com/url-3">Title 1Title 2Title 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/url-1http://www.example.com/url-2http://www.example.com/url-3">Title 1Title 2Title 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.example.com/url-1http://www.example.com/url-2http://www.example.com/url-3">Title 1Title 2Title 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a more optimal way of doing this?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a correct solution and for a detailed explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Replace this**:

```
@links = doc.xpath('//links/item').map do |i| 
  {'title' => i.xpath('//title'), 'url' => i.xpath('//url')}
```

**with**:

```
@links = doc.xpath('//links/item').map do |i| 
  {'title' => i.xpath('title'), 'url' => i.xpath('url')}
```

**Explanation**:

```
//title
```

and

```
//url
```

are *absolute* XPath expressions and they select all (respectively) `title` and all `url` elements in the XML document.

**Contrast this with**:

```
title
```

and

```
url
```

These are *relative* XPath expressions and select all (respectively) `title` and `url` children of the *current* node only.

Comment: Answer revoked, +1, since I assume you actually know what you're talking about. I don't know Xpath, and just guessed xD

Comment: @Matchu: Yes, I do know XPath and happen to be ranked #1 by rep in this tag. :) But your answer was correct -- you needn't delete it. Undelete it and I'll upvote.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm usually pretty picky about just letting one answer be up when there are dupes within seconds, though, since my OCD wins out over my insatiable hunger for rep. Thanks, though! You are a gentleman and a scholar :o

Comment: @Matchu: Please... Undelete your answer. I want to upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

The trouble here is that the Xpath `//title` searches for titles from the root of the document, and so returns all `title` tags. Using the Xpath `title` searches within the context of the given node, like you want. Ditto on `url`.

```
@links = doc.xpath('//links/item').map do |i|
  {'title' => i.xpath('title'), 'url' => i.xpath('url')}
end
```

Comment: Wow... I saw your undelete only now. Of course, the fully deserved +1. And I admired your explanation of the RegEx that decides if a number representation is composite!!!